# Каким способом можно ускорить выполнение данного кода?

Tags: python, время, pyautogui

Знаю что есть много подходов для ускорения выполнения кода, если можно поделиться простиньким методом для выполнения данного скрипта?

```
import pyautogui
import time

def func():
    start_time = time.time()
    count = 0
    new_list = []
    pyautogui.click(1376, 473)
    f = open(r"C:\Users\Alphabet\Python local\readme.txt", "r")
    for i in f:
        i = i.split(":")[0]
        new_list.append(i)

    value_to_parse = 500
    for y in new_list:
        if count < value_to_parse:
            pyautogui.typewrite(f"{y}\n")
            count += 1
        else:
            print(f"Injected: [{count} /{len(new_list)}]")
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
            break
func()
```

результат по итогу выполнения: --- 11.070001125335693 seconds ---

Comment: Попробуйте задать `interval` поменьше, наверняка на это всё время уходит. Ну, например: `pyautogui.typewrite(f"{y}\n", interval=0.1)`, я просто не знаю, какое там значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Таким способом не получается печатает по одному символу. Я думал добавить thereading или asyncio.